# nodejs + Mongodb: Inserting into two collections in sequence repeats last value in second

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I am using the following to insert into MongoDB.

```
var tagData = JSON.parse(data);
var allTags = tagData.tags;
for (var j = 0; j < allTags.length; j++) {
    var p = allTags[j].tagId.toString();
    for (var k = 0; k < loggerParams.length; k++) {
        var q = Object.keys(loggerParams[k]).toString();
        if (p === q) {
            // Prepare raw data tag
            var tagRawDoc = {};
            // Simple key-value assignment here
            // Document prepared; ready to insert into MongoDB
            database.addDocument('tagraw', tagRawDoc, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    log.info(util.format('Error adding document to tagrawdatas. %s', err.message));
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    // Prepare history tag
                    var historyTagDoc = {};
                    historyTagDoc.tagNameAlias = tagRawDoc.tagNameAlias;
                    // Simple key-value assignment here
                    // Document prepared; ready to insert into MongoDB
                    database.addDocument('taghistory', historyTagDoc, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            log.info(util.format('Error adding document to tagrawdatas. %s', err.message));
                            throw err;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            // Match found; exit loop
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `loggerParms` is a simple JSON document read from file else-where. It allows for look-up in this code to build the document to be inserted. There will be 12 values in the `allTags` array. These 12 values are inserted successfully into the `tagraw` collection. However, in `taghistory` collection, the values from the last (or most recent) entry made into `tagraw` collection is repeated 12 times. Why does this happen?

The `database.addDocument` is shown below. It is a part of [this article](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/processing-data-streams-with-amazon-kinesis-and-mongodb-atlas) I am trying to replicate.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var logger = require('../../util/logger');
var util = require('util');

function DB() {
    this.db = "empty";
    this.log = logger().getLogger('mongoMange-DB');
}

DB.prototype.connect = function(uri, callback) {
    this.log.info(util.format('About to connect to DB'));
    if (this.db != "empty") {
        callback();
        this.log.info('Already connected to database.');
    } else {
        var _this = this;
        MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, database) {
            if (err) {
                _this.log.info(util.format('Error connecting to DB: %s', err.message));
                callback(err);
            } else {
                _this.db = database;
                _this.log.info(util.format('Connected to database.'));
                callback();
            }
        })
    }
}

DB.prototype.close = function(callback) {
    log.info('Closing database');
    this.db.close();
    this.log.info('Closed database');
    callback();
}

DB.prototype.addDocument = function(coll, doc, callback) {
    var collection = this.db.collection(coll);
    var _this = this;
    collection.insertOne(doc, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
            _this.log.info(util.format('Error inserting document: %s', err.message));
            callback(err.message);
        } else {
            _this.log.info(util.format('Inserted document into %s collection.', coll));
            callback();
        }
  });
};

module.exports = DB;
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are mixing a/multiple synchronous `for` and asynchronous code with `database.addDocument` which cause issues with function scope in nodejs.

A simple example of this kind of thing:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 0);
}
```

You should use a package like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to handle flow control when iterating arrays/object asynchronously.

Simple example of your code refactored to use async:

```
var async = require('async');

var tagData = JSON.parse(data);
var allTags = tagData.tags;

async.each(allTags, function(tag, done){
    var p = tag.tagId.toString();
    var loggerParam = loggerParams.find(function(loggerParam){
        var q = Object.keys(loggerParam).toString();
        return p === q;
    });
    var tagRawDoc = {};
    // Simple key-value assignment here
    // Document prepared; ready to insert into MongoDB
    return database.addDocument('tagraw', tagRawDoc, function (err){
        if (err) return done(err);
        // Prepare history tag
        var historyTagDoc = {};
        historyTagDoc.tagNameAlias = tagRawDoc.tagNameAlias;
        // Simple key-value assignment here
        // Document prepared; ready to insert into MongoDB
        return database.addDocument('taghistory', historyTagDoc, done);
    });
}, (err) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('All done');
});
```

Comment: Since this code does not use subscripts, I am guessing, each entry in `allTags` is now `tag` and each entry in `loggerParams` is now `loggerParam`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes and instead of doing 2 loop i'm getting the `q` variable using `Array.find`  to avoid looping asynchronously over invalid values.

Comment: Got it. While preparing the `tagRawDoc`, I was indeed referring to `tag` and `loggerParam[q]`; however, the database is inserted with `null` values. Let me debug some more ....

Comment: use `tag` and `loggerParams[q]`, it should fix your issue.

Comment: The `loggerParams` is an array of objects (I should have mentioned this earlier). So, `q` will be an object whose value I need. I tried with `q[Object.keys(q)]` - tested it (here)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find]. However, at run-time, I get an error as `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` A match is guaranteed, by the way.

Comment: I've updated the code, should be clearer now and the `loggerParam` value should contain what you need

Comment: I have asked a more NodeJS knowledgeable colleague to take over. In the meantime, I closed the requirement with Python.